# Facebook pixel code in IE11 raises exception on .find

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer-11, facebook-pixel

I've noticed that the Facebook Pixel code now raises and exception in IE11. Seems like it is using a function that is not present in IE `.find`. I have no idea why or how to fix this?

Exception is: `object doesn't support property or method find`

It is using on multiple occasions in this file:

https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/XXXX?v=2.8.27&r=stable

[image]